# Use VBA as a substitute for RegEx

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have VBA code that uses the VBA VBScript libraries for the RegEx function, specifically. Lately several Anti Virus/Malware applications now disallow VBScript use in Office by default. I like the ease of Regular expressions, but I want to have my users avoid the issue altogether.

This is what I use. I have tried numerous capabilities with VBA and have not had any luck.
Any advice, please..?

```
    Public Function ValidateEmail(address As String) As Boolean
' Validate email address

Dim objRegExp As Object

On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"

    ValidateEmail = objRegExp.test(address)

    ' Release some memory
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
```

Comment: What does does `no luck` mean, exactly?  And what is the purpose of the Error handler?

Comment: VBA has `Like` but it's nowhere near as capable as the VBScript regex functionality.  You'd have to do quite a bit more work to duplicate those features.

Comment: Yes I have tried several different methods and the code is big and not as effective as RegEx. And, Ron, "No luck" means "No Luck" in duplicating the RegEx code with VBA. I have an error handler, but that leaves the input invalidated. Of course, the crash is avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use this "lo-tech" solution:

```vb
Public Function IsEmailAddress( _
    ByVal strEmailAddresses As String) _
    As Boolean

' Checks if strEMailAddr could represent one or more valid e-mail addresses.
' Does not check validity of domain names.
'
' 2003-06-22. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH
' 2018-12-01. Expanded to allow for and validate multiple addresses.

  ' Allowed characters.
  Const cstrValidChars    As String = "@_-.0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  Const cstrDot           As String = "."
  Const cstrAt            As String = "@"
  ' Minimum length of an e-mail address (a@a.ca).
  Const cintAddressLenMin As Integer = 6
  ' Address separator.
  Const cstrSeparator     As String = ";"
  
  Dim avarAddresses       As Variant
  Dim Index               As Integer
  Dim strEmailAddr        As String
  Dim strValidChars       As String
  Dim booFailed           As Boolean
  Dim intPos              As Integer
  Dim intI                As Integer

  If Trim(strEmailAddresses) = "" Then
    booFailed = True
  Else
    avarAddresses = Split(strEmailAddresses, cstrSeparator)
    For Index = LBound(avarAddresses) To UBound(avarAddresses)
      strEmailAddr = avarAddresses(Index)
      ' Strip a display name.
      CleanEmailAddress strEmailAddr
      ' Convert to lowercase.
      strEmailAddr = LCase(strEmailAddr)
      ' Check that strEMailAddr contains allowed characters only.
      For intI = 1 To Len(strEmailAddr)
        If InStr(cstrValidChars, Mid(strEmailAddr, intI, 1)) = 0 Then
          booFailed = True
        End If
      Next
      If booFailed = False Then
        ' Check that the first character is not cstrAt.
        booFailed = Left(strEmailAddr, 1) = cstrAt
        If booFailed = False Then
          ' Check that the first character is not a cstrDot.
          booFailed = Left(strEmailAddr, 1) = cstrDot
          If booFailed = False Then
            ' Check that length of strEMailAddr exceeds
            ' minimum length of an e-mail address.
            intPos = Len(strEmailAddr)
            booFailed = (intPos < cintAddressLenMin)
            If booFailed = False Then
              ' Check that none of the last two characters of strEMailAddr is a dot.
              booFailed = (InStr(intPos - 1, strEmailAddr, cstrDot) > 0)
              If booFailed = False Then
                ' Check that strEMailAddr does contain a cstrAt.
                intPos = InStr(strEmailAddr, cstrAt)
                booFailed = (intPos = 0)
                If booFailed = False Then
                  ' Check that strEMailAddr does contain one cstrAt only.
                  booFailed = (InStr(intPos + 1, strEmailAddr, cstrAt) > 0)
                  If booFailed = False Then
                    ' Check that the character leading cstrAt is not cstrDot.
                    booFailed = (Mid(strEmailAddr, intPos - 1, 1) = cstrDot)
                    If booFailed = False Then
                      ' Check that the character following cstrAt is not cstrDot.
                      booFailed = (Mid(strEmailAddr, intPos + 1, 1) = cstrDot)
                      If booFailed = False Then
                        ' Check that strEMailAddr contains at least one cstrDot
                        ' following the sign after cstrAt.
                        booFailed = Not (InStr(intPos, strEmailAddr, cstrDot) > 1)
                      End If
                    End If
                  End If
                End If
              End If
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
      If booFailed = True Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If
  
  IsEmailAddress = Not booFailed

End Function
```

and:

```vb
' Strips a full e-mail address with display name like:
'
'   "John Doe <john.doe@example.com>"
'
' to the e-mail address only:
'
'   "john.doe@example.com"
'
' 2018-12-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub CleanEmailAddress(ByRef EmailAddress As String)

    If Trim(EmailAddress) = "" Then
        EmailAddress = ""
    Else
        EmailAddress = Split(StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(EmailAddress), "<")(0)), ">")(0)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Gustav...may I use test and your code...?

Comment: Certainly. That's why I posted it. Upvote if you like it.